# VS2017 15.4 Preview "Windows Application Packaging Project" tool failed to generate a working app

Tags: wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge

I added the new "Windows Application Packaging Project" that comes with vs2017 15.4 preview.

When adding my project to the "Applications" and debugging the packaging project I have the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.'
>
> InnerException: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

My project is running perfectly if I debug it directly or run it directly using the EXE.

If I extract the files from the .appxbundle and try to start the EXE, it doesn't work either. (XXXXXX.appxbundle\XXXXXX.appx\*.*)

I noticed that in the extracted .appxbundle folder, all System.XXX DLLs are not there. They should be (94 dlls are missing).

Is there a problem with the packaging tool ?

---

UPDATE:

Link to dev portal: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/122252/windows-application-packaging-project-tool-failed.html

Comment: Which project did you try to use with the new packaging project? Can you share the project type and target framework?

Comment: It's a WPF project that targets .Net framework 4.7

Comment: WPF 4.7 applications do not require to copy all of the framework assemblies. .NET 4.7 should be previously installed in the target machine. I've not been able to reproduce with the default VS templates. Can you share your repro? or steps?

Comment: I have the netstandard 2 and netcore 2 packages installed in the WPF app. That's probably why I need those dlls.

Comment: Hi, Adrien. I've been able to reproduce and we have confirmed this is a bug in the current version of the packaging project. We are working on a resolution and I will update this thread once we have a fix. Rido [MSFT]

Comment: There is a quite similar issue with Sqlite package (we need to copy x86 and x64 folder in our solution and mark them to 'copy always'). Is there any 'official' way I can track this issue?

Comment: how are you using SqlLite? Using NuGet? Which format (packages.config or PackageRefereces? I would need more details to investigate. I'd recommend reporting problems as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017) and track those in the [Developer Community Portal](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/)

Comment: These are the NuGet packages: SQLite.Net-PCL // 
sqlite-net // 
SQLiteNetExtensions // 
System.Data.SQLite // 
System.Data.SQLite.Core // 
System.Data.SQLite.EF6 // 
System.Data.SQLite.Linq

Comment: We are still working on this issue. In the meanwhile, see this workaround proposed by another user: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/130144/windows-application-packaging-project.html

Comment: I will use the WiX Toolset setup project for now. I can't possibly copy every times the dlls as suggested in the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely a bug in the way the packaging project is collecting files. Looks like we're already tracking [this bug in the Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/130144/windows-application-packaging-project.html). Also, we're tracking another [related issue for ClickOnce](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/529).