# Windows Application Packaging Project says I need project.json for nuget?

Tags: windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge

It seems like [VS2017 15.4 Preview "Windows Application Packaging Project" tool failed to generate a working app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178608/vs2017-15-4-preview-windows-application-packaging-project-tool-failed-to-gener) but it's different:

I have a WAP project added to my WPF application.
The WAP is associated with the store. When I click create packages it says:

> Error     Your project.json doesn't list 'win10' as a targeted runtime. You should add '"win10": { }' inside your "runtimes" section in your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore. WapProject  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\15.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets  307

But the WAP project has no projects.json by default...

When I click the solution and manage nuget packages, there is this consolidate option because an old class lib uses json.net 5.x (because of jObject etc.) and the wpf app has 10.x

The main wpf app does build and run fine. Creating the packages is the issue.

edit: double clicking the error takes me to:

```
<ResolveNuGetPackageAssets Condition="Exists('$(FrameworkInjectionLockFile)')"
                           NuGetPackagesDirectory="$(FrameworkInjectionPackagesDirectory)"
                           RuntimeIdentifier="$(NuGetRuntimeIdentifier)"
                           TargetMonikers="$(NuGetTargetMonikerToInject)"
                           ProjectLockFile="$(FrameworkInjectionLockFile)">
```

manual adding a project.json to the WAP project did not fix it:

```
{
  "runtimes": {
    "win10": {},
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {}
  }
}
```

**edit2** consolidated the nuget packages. the wpf app builds, the class lib builds. the wap project does not:

> Error   APPX0501    Validation error. error 80080204: App manifest validation error: Line 24, Column 6, Reason: Windows.FullTrustApplication entry points are only valid for UWP desktop applications whose minVersion >= 10.0.14257.0. WapProject  C:\Users\blabla\Source\Workspaces\WapProject\bin\x86\Debug\AppxManifest.xml 1

and here is line 24:

```
<Application Id="App" Executable="WapProject.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
```

**edit3** went to the properties of the wapp and moved from anniversary update 14933 to the creator update and I can create the packages now. So it's solved. But how and why?

Comment: This was a known issue in the preview. Can you try with the latest Visual Studio 2017 Update 4 (15.4.1) ?

Comment: All fixed now. Waiting for my dev account to have sufficient privileges to add the packages for a store submission.

Comment: Do you know by any chance, how long it takes to get approved? It did not give an ETA.

Comment: As described [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge) you should be contacted in 6 business days

Comment: It usually goes much faster than this. Be sure to confirm your email address after you have registered. Let me know here if you still haven't heard back.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT where should I confirm the email address? I have got no mail (also checked spam folder). I think that this is the 3rd time I submitted the form.

Comment: That seems wrong - please contact me directly and we'll help you through the process - my email is swick at microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in the preview drop of Update 4. Fixed in the official version 15.4.1 of Visual Studio 2017 Update 4.